# Windows 10: Moving icloud photos to another drive?

Tags: icloud, windows, photos, photos.app

I would like to have a full local copy of my iCloud photos on my Windows 10 PC where I have local administrator rights.

Unfortunately the iCloud App installs without asking to the C: drive and that is too small to hold it all.  The preferences pane only allows me to provide the location of the shared albums, not the whole folder.

Apple only have instructions for MacOS:  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201517

I have seen hints that instead of changing the path inside the iCloud app, use a junction to point elsewhere.

What is the correct way as of 2021 to move iCloud Photos to another drive

Comment: Would Microsoft have instructions for Windows 10?

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, currently the only way is by using a junction:

1. Stop the iCloud app
2. Move the current folder to your new location:
   `Move "C:\Users\<user>\Pictures\iCloud Photos" "D:\Photos"`
3. Create a junction to point to your new location:
   `MkLink /J "C:\Users\<User>\Pictures\iCloud Photos" "D:\Photos"`

Please notice that in macOS based on the official guidelines, you do the same - move the location of the folder to another place...'